# How is my $PATH variable built on macOS?

Tags: macos, bash, path

I've recently installed [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) on my Mac and it's complaining that `/usr/bin` occurs before `/usr/local/bin` in my `$PATH` variable, meaning that system-provided programs will be used instead of those installed with Homebrew.

My `.bashrc` is configured in a set of separate files, as per this [screencast](https://web.archive.org/web/20161023044713/http://peepcode.com:80/products/advanced-command-line). This means that `~/.bash_profile` looks like this:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ];
then
  source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

`~/.bashrc` looks like this:

```
source ~/bin/dotfiles/bashrc
```

and `~/bin/dotfiles/bashrc` looks like this:

```
. ~/bin/dotfiles/bash/env
. ~/bin/dotfiles/bash/config
. ~/bin/dotfiles/bash/aliases
```

`~/bin/dotfiles/bash/env`, which is where I set my `$PATH` variable, looks like this:

```
export EDITOR="kom"
export PATH=some/path/at/start:usr/local/bin:/Users/jim/pear/bin:~/bin:/Users/jim/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/Users/jim/bin/bashscripts:some/path/at/end:$PATH
```

I've added `some/path/at/start` and `some/path/at/end` for debugging purposes, since when I try `echo $PATH` I get this:

`/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/jim/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:some/path/at/start:usr/local/bin:/Users/jim/pear/bin:/Users/jim/bin:/Users/jim/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/Users/jim/bin/bashscripts:some/path/at/end:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

That is, there's a load of other stuff being loaded into the $PATH variable that I can't control in the configuration I've outlined above. Any ideas as to where this stuff is loaded from, so that I can go about changing it and moving `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fix the typo in your PATH assignment and replace `usr/local/bin` with `/usr/local/bin` Homebrew should stop complaining.

The other stuff (`/opt/local/...`) is definitively added somewhere later during shell initialization (meaning after `source ~/.bashrc` or after `. ~/bin/dotfiles/bash/env`). You will have to look through the different files (or grep for `/opt/local` or `PATH.*PATH`) to see where it happens (and why).

Answer (score 4):

The INVOCATION section of the bash man page says

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading
>   that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and
>   ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the
>   first one that exists and is readable.

Of particular interest is `/etc/profile`, which uses `path_helper` to build a path from what it finds in `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d/*`.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the system wide bashrc, which is found at  /etc/bashrc, and a couple others.

From `man bash`:-

```
FILES
       /bin/bash
              The bash executable
       /etc/profile
              The systemwide initialization file, executed for login shells
       ~/.bash_profile
              The personal initialization file, executed for login shells
       ~/.bashrc
              The individual per-interactive-shell startup file
       ~/.bash_logout
              The individual login shell cleanup file, executed when a login shell exits
       ~/.inputrc
              Individual readline initialization file
```