# What modifies the PATH variable on macOS?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, path

`echo $PATH` returns a different result than the `PATH` variable I define in `.bashrc`. `.profile` is empty.

What else could be modifying the `PATH`variable?

The directories listed are all things I would have entered (i.e., not done by software), probably after having read something online, but I don't remember where.

This question is for macOS Mojave, not OS X Mountain Lion. Yes, the answers are the same, but the questions are not.

Comment: Are you checking PATH in a log in session or a new shell? There is a difference https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell

Comment: Unless proven wrong, answers based on older macOS versions remain valid. So this is indeed a duplicate of the question originally asked for Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system default `$PATH` variable is set in the file `/etc/paths`. That file has a one directory per line structure.

There are also multiple others files that can set or modify the path variable - user specific configuration files, and shell specific ones, that only apply if you use that specific shell.

I suggest not editing the system default file (`/etc/paths`) as it would affect all users. To add directories to the path used in a Terminal session (and assuming that you use the default bash shell), generate a file named .bash_profile. With a text editor, create a line that adds the directories you want to the default path, e.g:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$HOME/projects
```

That will add the directories "bin" and "projects" in your home directory to the system path. You will need to either execute `source .bash_profile` or restart your terminal session for that change to become effective.

Comment: Thank you so much for a thorough and educational answer.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use `grep` to find other files that modify `$PATH`, as is mentioned in a similar question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/64232/322902)? For example, `/Library/TeX/texbin` is being appended to my path, but it's not mentioned in either `/etc/paths`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, or `.profile`.